# Pass and modify a variable by reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reference

I have an event handling mechanism in one of the plugins I am building. I am triggering an event and want to the send a particular item back to the event handler param.

Inside, the event handler, I want to change the item that should also change it inside the plugin. I have a simple version of the same thing below.

`datafile.js`

```
var data = {
    'Project': [
        {
            'StartDate': '02/20/2013',
            'EndDate': '03/30/2013',
            'Description': 'Description 1',
            'ProjectID': 'ID1'
        },
        {
            'StartDate': '02/20/2013',
            'EndDate': '03/30/2013',
            'Description': 'Description 2',
            'ProjectID': 'ID2'
        }
]
};

function onbuttonClick() {
    onClickInternal(data.Project[1].Description);
};
```

Main index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="datafile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onClickInternal(description) {
            description = "This is the new description";
            document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = data.Project[1].Description;
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mydiv"> </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="onbuttonClick()" value="Project"/>
</body>
```

It won't make any sense if I pass the whole `data` object or `Project` array as the event handler param as I want to pass a specific `Description` item from and modify it so that it gets modified in the `data` array as well. How is this done in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

you can set only the arrayPos to you onClickInternal:

```
function onbuttonClick() {
    onClickInternal(1);
};

function onClickInternal(projectPos) {
    data.Project[projectPos].Description = "This is the new description";
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = data.Project[projectPos].Description;
};
```

or use a callback method

```
    function onbuttonClick() {
        onClickInternal(data.Project[1].Description, function(newDescription) {
            data.Project[1].Description = newDescription;
            return newDescription;
        });
    };


    function onClickInternal(description, setNewValue) {
        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = setNewValue("This is the new description");
    };
```

Comment: Ah! `data` won't be global in my plugin. Slipped from my mind wwhen I typed the code in the text code above. So the first approach can be modified if the `data` is not global?

Comment: Asked this because when I trigger the event, I am passing the params by something like `dataPlugin.events.trigger(this, "groupselect", this.itemSelected.index);`